# Cocos Builder Landscalpe UI shows up Portrait in IOS 6.1 simulator

Tags: cocosbuilder

I have made UI using Cocos builder in landscape mode. UI appears in landscape mode when I run the project in iphoneOS 5.0 simulator. When I run the same xCode project, UI shows shows up in portrait when the device is actually in landscape mode. How can I fix this problem?

Simulator screenshot for OS 6.0: 
[image]

Simulator screenshot for OS 5.0:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

When we created our project, we decided to use Cocos Builder. More than week I tried to adjust it and to start using but as to me it became sad when I saw that default builder examples are shown crooked. I do not recommend you to use cocos builder.